# Sound from video and audio elements not playing on iOS (not an autoplay issue)

Tags: javascript, html

I have made this little "app", which is basically a video of a fireplace and a Christmas song which will both play on a loop.

I sent it to a friend who has an Iphone and said that neither the audio from the video or the audio from the song is playing.

I have read many questions and documentations about this issue, but they all pretty much talk about how Apple don't let you use autoplay on load. Feature that (if I'm not wrong) Android uses too so that the audios need to be triggered by the user. But  that's ok, 'cause it's what I have done.

**How the audio is triggered on my app**

Since my app has `orientationchange` trigger I'll explain it to those who has not access to a phone or tablet (and I'll post the code obviously).

Once you access the website it tells you to turn your phone horizontally. After you've done it, a button will appear and by clicking (tapping) on it, both the video and audios start (at least on Adroid). So there *IS* an event triggered by the user. Under that button "sits" the `play()` for both audio and video elements. That's why, I can't understand what else should I do to make it work on iOS.

**Here the website if you want to take a look**

[The Website](https://myxmasplace.netlify.app)

EDIT: I tryied to make the snippet thing but somehow it appears broken, the JS code appears on the homepage. Have no clue why, so I'll simply copy the code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="balls.png" width="180px" class="balls" alt="xmas-balls">

    <div class="turncont">
      <h3 class="turn">Turn your phone</h3>
      <img src="turn.svg" class="turnicon" width="50px" alt="turn-smartphone-horizontally">
    </div>

    <h3 class="start">Start Magic</h3>
    
  </div>

  <video class="video" src="Fireplace.mp4" loop></video>
  <p class="home">Home</p>
  <img src="mobileup.svg" class="mobileup" width="30px" alt="">
  <audio src="ThereIsNoPlace.mp3" class="audio" loop></audio>

  <img src="frozen1.png" class="frozen1" alt="">
  <img src="frozen2.png" class="frozen2" alt="">
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Mountains of Christmas', cursive;
}

body {
  background: rgba(245,245,255);
}

.balls {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.turncont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.turn {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.start {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: .2em .9em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px limegreen;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: none;
}

.displaynone {
  display: none;
}

.displayyes {
  display: block;
}

.video {
  display: none;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: -5px;
}

.home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: none;
}

.mobileup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 12px;
  display: none;
}

.frozen1 {
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.frozen2 {
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
let start = document.querySelector('.start')
let turnStuff = document.querySelector('.turncont')
let balls = document.querySelector('.balls')
let mainCont = document.querySelector('.container')
let video = document.querySelector('.video')
let homeBtn = document.querySelector('.home')
let mobileUp = document.querySelector('.mobileup')
let audio = document.querySelector('.audio')

let frozen1 = document.querySelector('.frozen1')
let frozen2 = document.querySelector('.frozen2')

window.addEventListener('orientationchange', ()=> {

  if(screen.orientation.angle == 90 || screen.orientation.angle == 270 ) {

    start.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
      mainCont.style.display = 'none'
      video.style.display = 'flex'
      video.play()

      homeBtn.style.display = 'block'
      mobileUp.style.display = 'block'

      audio.play()
    })

    turnStuff.classList.add('displaynone')
    start.classList.add('displayyes')
    balls.style.top = '-10px'
    balls.style.width = '150px'

    frozen1.style.display = 'none'
    frozen2.style.display = 'none'
  }


  if(screen.orientation.angle == 0) {
    turnStuff.classList.remove('displaynone')
    start.classList.remove('displayyes')
    balls.style.top = '0px'
    balls.style.width = '180px'

    homeBtn.style.display = 'none'

    video.style.display = 'none'
    video.pause()
    video.currentTime = 0

    audio.pause()
    audio.currentTime = 0

    mainCont.style.display = 'block'
    mobileUp.style.display = 'none'

    frozen2.style.display = 'block'
    frozen1.style.display = 'block'
  }
  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna answer to it myself, because I managed to make it work.

I hope it's helpful for those who run into the same problem.

I'm not 100% sure that what I will say it's true, but by reading some documentation, apparently iOS or some versions of iOS doesn't support `orientationchange`, so I managed to make it work with `resize` instead, and also by changing the parameters of the conditional statement.

**I changed the event trigger**

```
window.addEventListener('resize', functionName)

  function functionName() {

    if(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {
    
      //then do stuff
    }
    
    if(window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {

    //then do other stuff
    }
}
```

**So the new JS is:**

```js
let start = document.querySelector('.start')
let turnStuff = document.querySelector('.turncont')
let balls = document.querySelector('.balls')
let mainCont = document.querySelector('.container')
let video = document.querySelector('.video')
let homeBtn = document.querySelector('.home')
let mobileUp = document.querySelector('.mobileup')
let audio = document.querySelector('.audio')
let snowCont = document.querySelector('.snowflakes')

let frozen1 = document.querySelector('.frozen1')
let frozen2 = document.querySelector('.frozen2')

window.addEventListener('resize', whenTurn)

function whenTurn() {

  if(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {

    turnStuff.classList.add('displaynone')
    start.classList.add('displayyes')
    balls.style.top = '-10px'
    balls.style.width = '150px'

    frozen1.style.display = 'none'
    frozen2.style.display = 'none'
  }


  if(window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {
    turnStuff.classList.remove('displaynone')
    start.classList.remove('displayyes')
    snowCont.style.display = 'block'
    balls.style.top = '0px'
    balls.style.width = '180px'

    homeBtn.style.display = 'none'

    video.style.display = 'none'
    video.pause()
    video.currentTime = 0

    audio.pause()
    audio.currentTime = 0

    mainCont.style.display = 'block'
    mobileUp.style.display = 'none'

    frozen2.style.display = 'block'
    frozen1.style.display = 'block'
  }
  
}

start.addEventListener('touchend', ()=> {
  mainCont.style.display = 'none'
  snowCont.style.display = 'none'
  video.style.display = 'flex'
  video.play()

  homeBtn.style.display = 'block'
  mobileUp.style.display = 'block'

  audio.play()
})
```